# Where can the Sample Music WMA files be found on the Windows XP installation CD?

Tags: windows-xp

More out of curiosity than anything - but where can the sample music files (in WMA format) be found on the original Windows XP installation CD? I realise that these will most likely need to be expanded before they can be played, but I haven't been able to find any references to these files when looking in the "I386" folder.